# Open source versions of Android phone icons

Tags: android, icons

Are there open source versions of the standard Options, Home, Back, and Search icons that appear on every phone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [this page](http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/), it offers a convenient way to browse the built-in drawables, most of which you can use just by referencing them in your layout.

See for example, the item `ic_menu_home`.  You can probably use it in a layout like so

```
<android:Whatever
     android:icon="@drawable/android:ic_menu_home"/>
```

Although, as the author of the page mentions, you sometimes have to copy items from the SDK resources folder if the above method throws an error.

Note also that while this method isn't guaranteed to match the icon you see, it will match what the user will see for that logical name.  For example, I used this technique to add the "Preferences" icon to an options menu, and the emulator had a different icon than what was shown there.  When you want a "standard" icon, this is good, although if you really wanted an exact image you could copy it into your app's `res` folder.

Comment: Great resource.  I noticed there is no standard Menu icon.  It appears that each vendor has their own take on the button.  So I will do the same for my purposes.

Comment: You should always copy default icon to your application because there is no guarantee that it will be available in future (and past) android platforms. Also design of icons differs between platforms and devices.

Comment: @piotpro, good point.  It probably 99% safe to reference, but you can be 100% sure by copying it.